# Non-English characters are not shown correctly in a mysql database inside phpMyAdmin (xampp)

Tags: mysql, encoding, character-encoding, phpmyadmin, non-english

**My problem:**

I'v been given a mysql database in a non-English language (Persian or Farsi, & if you don't know what kind of language is that, it's like Arabic). The records were entered through a web interface by php, using a windows machine. When I want to view the database using phpMyAdmin in xampp, the records look like this:

Ù…Ø±Ú©Ø² Ø¢Ù…ÙˆØ²Ø´ ØªÙˆÙ¾Ø®Ø§Ù†Ù‡ Ù†Ø²Ø§Ø¬Ø§

If I edit the records in phpMyAdmin, I can add non-English (Persian) characters and they look fine, only the existing data is incorrectly displayed.

I've been provided with a `.sql` backup file as well, but when I open it in Notepad++ it doesn't look right either. I also tried "Encode in UTF-8" in Notepad++, but no use.

**What I want:**

A correct representation in phpMyAdmin or a healthy .sql file.

**What I have:**

xampp 1.8.2 (Apache 2.4.4, MySQL 5.5.32, PHP 5.4.16, phpMyAdmin 4.0.4), win 7 x64

The files I have:
`.frm .MYD .MYI` files (which I copied to `xampp\mysql\data\mxpro`), the `.sql` file i mentioned (`mxpro.sql`) & `db.opt` file containing these 2 lines:

```
default-character-set=utf8
default-collation=utf8_general_ci
```

I've found this line included inside the `.sql` file:

```
CHARSET=latin1
```

All of these files are inside a folder called '`mxpro`' located in `xampp\mysql\data\`.

The collation of the table columns in the phpMyAdmin are: `latin1_swedish_ci`

**What I have tried:**

First of all, when I open the `MYI` file in Notepad++ and use "Encode in UTF-8", I can see most of the data sitting there in the correct format (Persian).

I've tried the following based on my research:

1) Changing whatever I see to `utf8_general_ci`, including: database (mxpro) collation (through operations), table collation (through operations), columns collation & server connection collation (in general settings)

2) Changing these server variables to `utf8`: character set client, character set connection, character set database, character set results, character set server & character set system.

3) Changing these server variables to `utf8_unicode_ci`: collation connection, collation database & collation server.

4) Adding this line:

```
@MySQL_Query("SET NAMES utf8");
```

to xampp\php\pear\MDB2\Driver\mysql.php after this line:

```
$connection = @call_user_func_array($connect_function, $params);
```

5) Adding these 3 lines to my.ini:

```
collation_server=utf8_unicode_ci
character_set_server=utf8
skip-character-set-client-handshake
```

6) Adding these 2 lines:

```
mysqli_query($link, "SET SESSION CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS =latin1;");
mysqli_query($link, "SET SESSION CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT =latin1;");
```

to xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\dbi\mysql.dbi.lib.php, below the following line:

```
PMA_DBI_postConnect($link, $is_controluser);
```

7) Changing this:

```
'utf-8'        => 'utf8',
```

to this:

```
'utf-8'        => 'latin1',
```

in xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\select_lang.lib.php

despite my efforts, no outcome yet.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: umm... you're dealing with farsi, but the database tables are set to `latin1_swedish`? No wonder everything's getting trashed. You should be using UTF-8 only, everywhere, and the problems would go away.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do, but no results. The project was developed by someone else until now and it has about 2500 records.

Comment: you know i had that problem too with my Xampp. I inserted a row which contained some Farsi character and i get "?" instead. then i tried to use phpMyAdmin and thats done! every thing become ok easily inserted. so i found that my CMD command line was not sent utf8 character to mysql so that was my problem there ( ofc i did some changes on my.ini too but dont know if they affected on some thing or not )

Answer (score 0):

On the phpMyAdmin wiki, there is an article explaining this issue:

http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Garbled_data

Answer (score 0):

I used this query on my db and it's worked perfectly

> `ALTER DATABASE yourDB CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin`